# How to take data as a String in android retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "email": "janet.weaver@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Janet",
        "last_name": "Weaver",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg"
    }
```

This is json formatted data API. I want to take just email part as a String to my android app with using retrofit than i will print this string to textView.

down below there is my getFromAPI interface.

```
public interface getFromAPI {
    @GET("api/users/2")
    Call<TextView> getData();
}
```

Here is my Model class:

```
public class Model {

    @SerializedName("email")
    public String mail;

}
```

Here is my variables and other gson things.

```
Model mod;
Retrofit retrofit;
TextView textView;

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
```

Here is my call.enqueue() method.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<TextView>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TextView> call, Response<TextView> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    TextView text = response.body();
                    mod = new Model();

                    System.out.println(mod);
                }
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TextView> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

First i wanted to printing it to the console but this code doesnt printing to the console. I couldnt figure it out. Help me please.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want you want your call to return a TextView, but I would suggest you update your interface to take in your model  -> Call<Model>

Comment: i fix that to Call<Model> still i got nothing

Comment: Can you edit the code and make it like after changing to Call<Model>

Comment: i did that but i think i looking that so simple so i should resarch more, thank you for comments.